# Unable to find Boost libraries with CMake and vcpkg

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, vcpkg

I have installed `boost-variant2` library using the vcpkg command:

> vcpkg install boost-variant2:x64-windows

When vcpkg finished the installation, it prompted this:

```
The package boost is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(Boost REQUIRED [COMPONENTS <libs>...])
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::<lib1> Boost::<lib2> ...)
```

so in my CMakeLists.txt I added the following lines:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS variant2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE Boost::variant2)
```

However, when I run `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING=/path_to_vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` I get the following error:

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> Could NOT find Boost (missing: variant2) (found version "1.78.0")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like variant2 is header-only lib and you can just use Cmake file like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(project LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(project main.cpp)
```

U can see list of libs required to be built for [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) for Windows and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) for Unix-like systems